# Upper bound on the diameter of a graph from the expander mixing lemma

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose $G=(V,E)$ is a $d$-regular graph on $n$ vertices satisfying the conclusion of the [expander mixing lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expander_mixing_lemma), namely for all $S,T\subseteq V$

$$\left|E(S,T)-\frac{d|S||T|}{n}\right|\le \frac{d\sqrt{|S||T|}}{3}$$

where $E(S,T)$ is the number of edges of $G$ with one endpoint in $S$ and one endpoint in $T$. I want to prove that this implies that the diameter of $G$ is $O(\log n)$.

---

I thought that one possible way to approach the problem is by trying to lower bound the number of vertices at distance $t$ from a fixed vertex $u$. However it seems that my assumption only gives a nontrivial lower bound on $E(S, V\setminus S)$ when $|S|=\Omega(n)$.